# How to Navigate view Controller form Navigation Controller Programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Hi I'm trying navigate to view controller form the navigation view controller with connect using the objects

i want to do by programmatically but its not working its showing the black screen. Please tell me how to resolve this.

```
- (IBAction)reg:(id)sender {
    pollpoliticalViewController *vc2 = [[pollpoliticalViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
}
```

The above code i have used to navigate but its giving black color screen its not showing the view controller please tell me where I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with the above code.

As I understand what you are doing, you have a view controller class called `pollpoliticalViewController`. My first suggestion would be for you to look into the accepted coding style in Objective-C. You should always capitalise classes. In this instance the class should have been called 'PollPoliticalViewController`. Obviously this is not the source of the problem though.

The problem will be with the view controller itself. In the code for pollpoliticalViewController you are doing something wrong which is not displaying the view.

The view controller may actually be styled inside of a .xib file, in which case you should be initialising the view controller like this:

```
pollpoliticalViewController *pollVC = [[pollpoliticalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"pollpoliticalViewController" bundle:nil];
```

If the view controller is defined inside of a storyboard, you will have to give the view controller a 'Storyboard ID', for example; 'PollPoliticalVCID'. You then need to initialise it like this (assuming your storyboard is called "MainStoryboard":

```
pollpoliticalViewController *pollVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PollPoliticalVCID"];
```

**EDIT**

The storyboard name is found when you open the storyboard, do **not** select any view controller. Open the Utilities side bar (on the right side of Xcode), select the first item, and you can find the name under Identity and Type. I have included an image.

[image: Storyboard Name]

Comment: @infiity james im using the story board

Comment: @james its showing we not able to find the story borad name pls tell where ihave to check the story board name

Comment: @user3349668 I have updated the answer to tell you the name of the sotryboard.

Comment: @james i have tried that one also its not working its giving same error

Comment: You need the name of YOUR STORYBOARD FILE. Not the example one that I gave.

Comment: @james i have my story board name only in my story board name is Main.storyboard i have this one also its not working pls tell where i can found the story board name

Comment: @user3349668 The name of the storyboard in your case will be @"Main". Feel free to email me your code and I'll look at it: james@infinityjames.com

Comment: @james can u come on chat box so we can discuss details

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49815/discussion-between-infinity-james-and-user3349668)